# I keep getting "foreign key references invalid column?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, database-schema

I'm referencing the primary key of the table, which is also a foreign key. The exact error I'm getting is this:
***"Foreign key 'customer_username' references invalid column 'customer_username' in referencing table 'CustomerAddstoCartProduct'."***

```
create table Customers(
username varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
points int
FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES Users ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

)
create table CustomerAddstoCartProduct (
serial_no int, 
customer_name varchar (20)
PRIMARY KEY(serial_no, customer_name)
FOREIGN KEY(serial_no) REFERENCES Products ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(customer_username) REFERENCES Customers ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your foreign keys declarations are malformed, they are missing the referred column in the target table.

Eg, in table `CustomerAddstoCartProduct`, you should have:

```
FOREIGN KEY(customer_username) REFERENCES Customers(username) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Instead of:

```
FOREIGN KEY(customer_username) REFERENCES Customers 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

---

Another thing that is akward is that, in table `Customers`, your primary key column has a foreign key constraint. While this might work, this probably indicates a design issue. If you have a 1:1 relationship between `Customers` and `Users`, you should probably be storing all columns in the same table.

Comment: @LobnaHishamEldeeb: there are 3 foreign keys declaration in the declaration of the tables, and they all have the same issue. You need to fix them all.

Answer (score 0):

Include the column being referenced and use the correct column name:

```
create table CustomerAddstoCartProduct (
    serial_no int, 
    customer_name varchar(20)
    PRIMARY KEY(serial_no, customer_name)
    FOREIGN KEY(serial_no) REFERENCES Products (serial_no) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_name) REFERENCES Customers (username) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fdb234162b255babeb31828a4a3ff992) is a db<>fiddle -- with the extraneous table references commented out.

Comment: does `Products` not need a field specifier because there's a `serial_no` key there too?

Comment: @DanielFarrell . . . Yes it should have one.